# Noun form at the end of a sentence with many objects

Tags: singular-vs-plural, coordination

If there is a high school ***student*** and a university ***student***.

Can we say,

> There ***are*** a high school ***student*** and a university ***student***.

or

> There ***is*** a high school ***student*** and a university ***student***.

or

> There ***is*** a high school and a university ***student***.

or

> There ***are*** a high school and a university ***students***.

But if one group is greater than one. Let's say

There is a high school student and three university students.

Can we say,

> There ***are*** a high school and three university ***students***.

or

> There ***are*** a high school ***student*** and three university ***students***.

or

> There ***is*** a high school ***student*** and three university ***students***.

I am confused here how to make the sentences right according to the grammar rules.

Comment: Related: **[“There Is”/“There are” depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not)**

Answer (score 2):

In academic writing, the plural form "there are" should be used whenever the following noun phrase is plural. However, most other writing is much more lax about this, and you'll often find "there is" or "there's" being used with plural noun phrases, especially when the first element by itself is singular.

It seems this issue was a big deal over at EL&U: "[“There Is”/“There are” depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not)"

The third, fourth, and fifth sentences you asked about are all incorrect.

Most style guides recommend you avoid syntactic expletives (there is/are/was/were) altogether and favor a different sentence construction.